# Thermodynamic equilibrium- mixing of gases

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics

What is the final temperature and pressure after removing diaphragm of a cylinder which divides the cylinder into two equal components each of volume $0.1\,m^3$ and each component contains air at $20^\circ C$ and pressure of 2.5 MPa and 1 MPa respectively.

And also, please give me basic concepts for approaching these types of problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you're modelling the gases in question as ideal gases, we have:

1) The sum of the internal energy of the gas is the sum of the internal energies of the gases in the separate compartments:

$$U = U_{1} + U_{2} $$

$$U = nC_{v}T$$ where $n$ = number of moles, $C_{v}$ = specific heat capacity at constant volume, and $T$ = temperature

2) Solving for $T$, we get:

$T = (n₁T₁ + n₂T₂) / (n₁ + n₂)$

where we use $n_{1} = P_{1}V_{2}/RT_{2}$ and $n_{2} = P_{2}V_{2}/RT_{2}$

Since $T_{1} = T_{2}$ temperature will not change. i.e. $T = 20^{\circ} C$

3) Likewise, the final pressure can be found via the ideal gas law:

$P = (n₁ + n₂)RT / V $

plugging in values for pressure gives: $1.75 Mpa$

Answer (score 0):

If you are considering air as an ideal gas, then your final pressure would be 1.75MPa, which is the averages of the two since your components have equal volume. Temperature would not change.

However if you are considering air as a real gas, you would need to use Joule-Thomson coefficient to find $\partial{T}/\partial{P}$. Which in this case probably wouldn't matter anyway since the pressure increase of the first component equals the pressure decrease of the second, which cancels out.